# Trying to start MySQL but start is disabled

Tags: xampp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLELK.jpg) how do I solve this I’m new to programming. I’m researching corners of internet

Enable the start button is disabled and can’t find a solution how do I go about fixing this. What do i need to fix